# Set input box value from session mobile device

Tags: php, html, session

I have two forms, one on homepage where user can use firstname, lastname, date, time, email. And also on another page i have the some form with the some fileds where i need to copy value from first form on homepage.

When user submit first form on homepage i get that values and put in session.
In second form on another page i check if session key exist and put it like input value. All that work perfect in browser on any PC. When i try to test on mobile device  session value is now showed. He show just empty fields.

```
<input type="date"  name="pickup_date" value="<?= isset($_SESSION['pickup_date']) ? $_SESSION['pickup_date'] : null;?> " class="datepicker form-control alt"></div>
```

All other filds have the some code. Whay on mobile divece value is not showed but in pc bowser work fine?

**Update:**
For datepicking i use jquery ui.
On mobile device i want to show default mobule databicker slider . SO i first check if is mobile device with `ontouchstart` event and then change input type from `text` to `date`.Phone input date in this format `YY-MM-DD` but filed except `MM/DD/YY`. I thing that is bug in my code

Comment: check session_id() on each page with var_dump. values should be the same.

Comment: Ok, i will check now

Comment: Session id is the some. I think i found bug. I will edit post check for update

Comment: I need to change date format i think